# Creating a custom method to draw - Graphics 2D g2 is null

Tags: java, swing, graphics, null, drawing

I am trying to solve the following problem: Write a program that displays the Olympic rings. Color the rings in the Olympic colors. Provide a method drawRing that draws a ring of a given position and color.

---

I am having a major issue with my understanding of how exactly objects of type Graphics work. I initially tried using`getGraphics()` to pass it as a parameter to the method however i learned that this method is typically avoided as null exceptions are likely to occur. So i read that you should override the `paintComponent` method in the component class? so i tried this by making a class containing the override and my `drawRing` method, making Graphics2D g2 an instance variable however i am still getting a null error once it is called upon in the first line of `drawRing`. I have been trying to figure something out for hours but I'm really not sure how to approach this problem to make the method have access to the frame in main and if there's an entirely different way i should be tackling it. Any help is much appreciated.

---

Also, I would just like to note that I have not begun accounting for x and y coordinates as well as color in my `drawRing` method, I first want to make sure the program can access the method and that it can draw on the frame made in main first, afterwards I figure those details will be fairly simple.

---

My Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class test{
    public static class ringComponent extends JComponent{
        private Graphics2D g2;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        }
        public void drawRing(){
            g2.setColor(Color.RED);//Null error here
            Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 200, 200);
            g2.draw(circle);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 800;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 800;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Olympic Rings");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ringComponent rc = new ringComponent();
        rc.drawRing();
        frame.add(rc);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT be defining a "g2" variable.

You should NOT invoke the drawRing() method.

Instead the code from the drawRing() method should be placed in the paintComponent() method. Swing will then invoke the paintComponent() method automatically when the component needs to be repainted.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: This is actually the way i learned to draw however doing it that way i cannot make a separate method that can take coordinates and string as parameters which is the source of my problem in the first place because i cannot alter the paramaters of paintComponent.

Comment: `i cannot make a separate method that can take coordinates and string as parameters` - sure you can. You can add any method to your class that you want to customize your painting. That is how Swing components works. Methods like setText(), setForeground(), setBackground() all affect the way a component is painted. If you have special painting requirements then you create appropriate "setter" methods that allow you to change these values. Then in the setter method you invoke `repaint()` and the component will repaint itself.

Comment: So if it is possible to make my own method within the class, how exactly would i go about doing so? If i declare the method within the paintComponent method i get an illegal start of expression error, and declaring it outside is exactly what i tried above which did not work.

Comment: @user2023740, `If i declare the method within the paintComponent method i get an illegal start of expression error` I didn't say to move the method, I said move the code (and then delete the empty method).

Comment: But again i need to be able to call the method with the parameters: drawRing(int x, int y, String color);, if i move the code and delete the  method how can i achieve this?

Comment: @user2023740, the same way all "setter" methods work. You save the properties in the class and then invoke repaint(). The paintComponent() method will then reference these properties when the component is repainted. Take a look at the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). The `addRectangle()` method is invoked whenever a new Rectangle is to be added to the image. Your code could be very similar except you would be drawing ovals and you would add the ovals manually instead of by using the mouse.

Comment: Okay i was not aware that repaint() invoked paintComponent() so this makes much more sense to me now. I then ran into an issue where every time i drew a new ring the old one was erased however i fixed that  issue by mimicking the method used in the example you linked by adding each ring to a list and making paintComponent() draw each element every time repaint() is invoked. Anyway thank you very much for your help I couldn't have done it without you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course `g2` is null. You haven't called `paintComponent`, so it hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: i tried calling paintComponent with the line: rc.paintComponent(frame.getGraphics()); just before rc.drawRing(); but its the same null error.